# Abstract structure of Matrix-Vector multiplicaiton?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vectors

Algebraic structures such as groups are generally defined on a set $A$ so that if $a,b\in A$, then both $a*b$ and $b*a$ are defined. However, matrix-vector multiplication is such that if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, then $Ax$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, but $xA$ is undefined.

However, matrix-vector multiplication is associative when more than one matrix is involved (as in (AB)x=A(Bx)), making it similar to a semi-group. It has other somewhat group-like properties, like an identity element. Hence it seems like a structure like this (the set of all $m\times n$ matrices together with the set of all $n$-dimensional vectors and the operation of matrix-vector multiplication) would be studied by abstract algebra. Is there an abstract algebra structure (such as a semi-group, group, etc.) which studies structures like this?

Comment: And *group action* isn't the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks, I need frequent reminders that non-invertible matrices exist :)

Comment: better to think of this matrix "multiplication" as *composition* of maps. Then the structure is like any other composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) here. The objects are the natural numbers $n$
and the morphisms between $m$ and $n$ are the $m$-by-$n$ matrices.
Composition of morphisms is multiplication of matrices. (You can think
of vectors as $m$ by $1$ matrices.)

Comment: Why not simply the category of finite dimensional vector spaces (which is the same as your category)?

Comment: @Hamed "the same as" is not easy to interpret in category theory! My category is certainly not isomorphic to the category of f.d. vector spaces (too few objects!) but is equivalent to it (If I count zero as a "natural number"). It is isomorphic to the full subcategory of vector spaces with objects $F^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The action of $m \times n$ matrices (over a field $\mathbb F$) on the vector space $\mathbb F^n$ corresponds to the linear maps from $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F^n$, i.e. $\text{Hom}(\mathbb F^n, \mathbb F^m)$.